# Keras model to plot gives none, dimensions

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to plot VGG16 architecture diagram using Keras. However, i see the below image with `None`, some dimension. What does `None` mean, is that a bug ?

[image]

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
model = VGG19(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
#print(model.summary())
plot_model(model, to_file='model_Vgg19.png',show_shapes=True)
```

I can see that this is a known issue in Keras: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1877.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/49705084/2679386

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `None` dimension in the shape tuple refers to the batch dimension which simply means that the layer can accept input of any size. For example, a dataset (e.g. MNIST) could have the following shape tuple `(60000, 28, 28, 1)` but the input layer's shape would be `(None, 28, 28, 1)`.

References:

- [keras-team/keras#2054](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2054)
- [Keras Documentation - Core Layers](https://keras.io/layers/core/)