# Question mark (?) on the output of Keras plot_model

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

Using Keras, I am plotting my model this way:

```
import keras
import pydotplus
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
keras.utils.vis_utils.pydot = pydot

#plot_model(loaded_model, to_file='model.png')

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(loaded_model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

The plotting works, however, I am getting question marks ("?") on the first of each shape. For example:
input: [(?,1250,2)]

Is the question mark the same as "none"? (the "none" was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935253/keras-model-to-plot-gives-none-dimensions)) If not, what is the reason for the "?"?

[image]

Comment: Yes it the same. `?` refers to the size of input (Batch_size) usually

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil is there a way of replacing the "?" by none? Side note: I am running this on Jupyter.